# how to specify xsd with wcf restful webservice

Tags: wcf, rest, xsd, schema

I have a restful wcf webservice that emits the following xml:

```
<foo xmlns="http://www.contoso.com" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Name>Amy</Name>
    <Score>78</Score>
</foo>
```

The wcf service contract is decorated like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/getperson/{parm1}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
```

How do i get a link to the xsd added into the generated xml so that when a client consumes it, they will have a schema to read?